# How to ignore particular keys inside .properties files while converting to json

Tags: json, linux, bash, application.properties

I have .property file which I'm trying to convert to a json file using bash command(s) and I wanted to exclude particular keys being shown in the json file. Below are my .properties inside the property file, I want to exclude property 4 and 5 being converted to json

```
app.database.address=127.0.0.70
app.database.host=database.myapp.com
app.database.port=5432
app.database.user=dev-user-name
app.database.pass=dev-password
app.database.main=dev-database
```

Here's my bash command used for converting to json but it converts all the properties to json

`cat fle.properties | jq -R -s 'split("\n") | map(split("=")) | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add' > zppprop.json`

Is there any way we can include these parameters to exclude from converting to json

Comment: hi perhaps grep them out with `grep -v` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may filter out unneeded lines with grep:

```
cat fle.properties | grep -v -E "user|pass" | jq -R -s 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0)) | map(split("=")) | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add'
```

It is also needed to remove the empty string at the end of the array returned by the `split` function. This is what `map(select(length > 0))` is doing.

Comment: Useless `cat`. Simply do: `grep -v -E "user|pass" fle.properties | jq…`

Answer (score 2):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

**XPath + JSONiq solution**

```
$ xidel -s fle.properties -e '
  {|
    x:lines($raw)[not(position() = (4,5))] ! {
      substring-before(.,"="):substring-after(.,"=")
    }
  |}
'
{
  "app.database.address": "127.0.0.70",
  "app.database.host": "database.myapp.com",
  "app.database.port": "5432",
  "app.database.main": "dev-database"
}
```

- [`x:lines($raw)`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-lines) is a shorthand for `tokenize($raw,'\r\n?|\n')` and turns `$raw`, the raw input, into a sequence where every new line is another item.
- `[not(position() = (4,5))]` if it's always the 4th and 5th line you want to exclude. Otherwise, use `[not(contains(.,"user") or contains(.,"pass"))]` as seen below.

**XQuery solution**

```
$ xidel -s --xquery '
  map:merge(
    for $x in file:read-text-lines("fle.properties")[not(contains(.,"user") or contains(.,"pass"))]
    let $kv:=tokenize($x,"=")
    return
    {$kv[1]:$kv[2]}
  )
'
{
  "app.database.address": "127.0.0.70",
  "app.database.host": "database.myapp.com",
  "app.database.port": "5432",
  "app.database.main": "dev-database"
}
```

- You can use [`file:read-text-lines()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#file-read-text-lines) to do everything "in-query".

[Playground.](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable+all+extensions&data=app.database.address%3D127.0.0.70%0D%0Aapp.database.host%3Ddatabase.myapp.com%0D%0Aapp.database.port%3D5432%0D%0Aapp.database.user%3Ddev-user-name%0D%0Aapp.database.pass%3Ddev-password%0D%0Aapp.database.main%3Ddev-database&extract=map%3Amerge(%0D%0A++for+%24x+in+x%3Alines(%24raw)%5Bnot(position()+%3D+(4%2C5))%5D%0D%0A++let+%24kv%3A%3Dtokenize(%24x%2C%22%3D%22)%0D%0A++return%0D%0A++%7B%24kv%5B1%5D%3A%24kv%5B2%5D%7D%0D%0A)&extract-kind=xquery3.0&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the exclusion within the jq script:

`properties2json`

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -sRf

split("\n") |
map(split("=")) |
map(
  if .[0] | test(".*\\.(user|pass)";"i")
  then
    {}
  else
    {(.[0]): .[1]}
  end
) |
add
```

```sh
# Make it executable
chmod +x properties2json

# Run it
./properties2json file.properties >file.json
```